# Corda Enterprise - Could not find com.r3.libs:r3-libs-obfuscator:1.0

Tags: corda

I am provided with Corda Enterprise artifacts to test our solution against it. We don't yet have a enterprise support, this is still a non tech work in a process, so I am asking here a tech question:
After downloading all the developer pack artifacts from Corda Enterprise 4.5 and putting them in my local maven repository I continue to get the following error  `Could not resolve com.r3.libs:r3-libs-obfuscator:1.0`.
I spent many hours trying to find a solution but I could not find even a clue about this particular jar file. There is nothing at all related to it in the Internet.
I searched the slack channel of Corda and there are at least 5 people facing the same issue that I do, but nobody seems to have found the solution to this. Some people tell that his can be related to `corda-tools-config-obfuscator-4.5-GA.jar` somehow, but I don't think so, as this jar is right there in my repository and anyways the name and the package of the missing jar is different.
The only way to build cordapp was to exclude this dependency from any Corda dependency that relays on this one. One of such a dependency is `corda-node` btw, but this seems to be a wrong solution as I exclude a transient dependency from artifacts that I don't own, and I have no clue on when this excluded package might be needed to `corda-node` dependency and how exactly will it fail in absence of this one.

So please can someone from Corda Enterprise team give us a hint on what this jar is and where can we find it. I have a feeling that someone just forgot to put it in the developer pack of Corda Enterprise artifacts...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like it is a missing dev pack library issue, basically.
The de-obfuscation code is now common across CENM and Corda and is hence a separate library.

You can find them here: https://software.r3.com/artifactory/webapp/#/artifacts/browse/tree/General/r3-tools-dev/com/r3/libs/r3-libs-obfuscator/1.0-SNAPSHOT/r3-libs-obfuscator-1.0-20200409.080322-2.jar

You might need to contact your account manager to get it if you currently don't have access to it.